# Dialogs and FPS changes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog, frame-rate

This is a pretty broad question, but does anyone know why dialogs seem to affect framerate on Android? For example, when I show and dismiss a dialog while my game is running, the movement becomes slow and choppy. However, the framerate of an in-game explosion improves. I have tried about every single thing I can think of, and nothing seems to help. Any help is **greatly** appreciated.

How I show the dialogs:

```
private void showPauseMenu() {
    isRunning = false; //tells the game thread that the game is no longer running
    paused = true; //tells the game thread that the game is paused
    ourThread = null; // nulls the Thread object until the game is resumed
    pause.show();
}
```

How I get rid of the dialog and start the game again:

```
isRunning = true;
ourThread = new Thread(this);
if (paused) {
    paused = false;
    pause.dismiss();
}
ourThread.start();
```

FPS calculation

```
    if (elapsedTime < 33) {
        timeToSleep = 33 - elapsedTime;
    } else {
        timeToSleep = 0;
        Log.i("fps", "sleeping over 33ms");
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("fps", "" + 1000 / (elapsedTime + timeToSleep));
```

Comment: Anyone? I'm desperate here.

Comment: No, I don't. I'm just using java's graphics.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog is also run in UI thread. The more workload run in UI thread cause lower FPS. Even if you run your game logic in your game thread, all graphics work are still run in UI thread. That's why the dialog will affect your FPS.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But even after I dismiss the dialog, the performance is hindered. Also, one aspect of the game actually gets better fps after the dialog is shown and dismissed.

Comment: How did you calculate the FPS? could you post the code? assume your time cost before/after is 30ms, 30ms,50ms(width dialog),50ms,30ms,30ms

Comment: if (elapsedTime < 33) {
timeToSleep = 33 - elapsedTime; 
} else {
timeToSleep = 0;
Log.i("fps", "sleeping over 33ms");
}
try {
Thread.sleep(timeToSleep);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("fps", ""+1000/(elapsedTime+timeToSleep));

Comment: Alas, I don't know how to post code in comments. Basically I set a target time to sleep (33ms) and it is actually sleeping 33 ms each time, meaning the FPS is constant. However, the visuals still get very choppy and slow.

Comment: you can edit your post, and paste it to your question. about your FPS, it is not the real FPS. You did the calculation in your thread. To calculate the FPS, you have to write code in your UI thread. That's why you were confused about the FPS value

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for those. However, regardless of what the FPS is, it is still very noticeably changing (both up and down) even if I only show and dismiss one dialog. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Since the dialog will affect the FPS, you should pause the game first. I didn't see any synchronization in showPauseMenu(). the code can't guarantee the game thread stop first. you can use atomic boolean value, and try ourThread.join() before ourThread = null.

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception. I a bit new to threads, could you point me in the right direction? EDIT: The showPauseMenu() method is called from the touchListener if that helps.

Comment: Also, I'm using ourThread.join() in my actual onPause() method, just not in the showPauseMenu() method I've created, since the activity itself isn't necessarily pausing, but just the game movements are.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44761/discussion-between-yushulx-and-armaak)